# Is there a function in tkinter to figure out the screen orientation

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to make an app for Android as my school project I'm using tkinter and wanted to know if there's a function that can just tell you the screens orientation

I tried using a loop to compare the screens height and width and then determine the orientation that way but the window didn't appear because of the loop. Pls help kinda need to submit in 2 weeks. I'm also okay with a way to make it so that the above mentioned loop doesn't stop the window appearing

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Tkinter on an Android?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I had the same reaction. Maybe OP knows something we don't? ;)

Comment: @JRiggles I mean we can run `tkinter` on some python interpreters we download from Play Store but it would be really disoriented. Better off choosing a different framework and maybe even a different language

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Just carry your desktop with you! It's so simple. But yeah, kidding aside, tkinter is probably not the right tool here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria yeah I am just trying to prototype and found an interpreter that let me mess around with Android development but I am trying to learn kivy for better gui and stuff

Answer (score 1):

If your end user is using a single monitor, you can probably get away with something like this

```
root = tk.Tk()


def get_screen_orientation():
    width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    if width >= height:
        return 'Landscape'
    return 'Portrait'
```

It gets trickier on multi-monitor setups, however, because only the dimensions of the primary monitor will be shown.

EDIT: I am not aware of any way to create a mobile app using tkinter (at time of writing). However, I'm gonna leave this answer up because it is still viable in a typical tkinter app. You have been warned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try to implement it